# Use induction to show that $\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{i-1} (k-i) = 2^k -k -1, k\ge1$

Tags: summation, proof-writing, induction

This is an exercise question in Fundamentals of Computer Algorithms by Horowitz and Sahni. The base case for this is trivial. However for the inductive case, we need to verify, $p(n) \implies p(n+1)$ is true.

In the above summation, plugging in the values, with $i=k$, the term evaluates to $2^{k-1} (k-k)$ which evaluates to $0$. Regardless of the number of terms, the last term of the series is $0$. I was trying to evaluate the inductive step, however, was unable to proceed further.

I am not looking for a full solution, just hints and pointers to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The induction should be on $k$ **not** on $i$. The index $i$ is just a **dummy index** used for summation. So assume that it is true for $k=n$ and then prove that it can be true for $k=n+1$.

Comment: For $p(n) :  k = n$. Let us assume $p(n)$ is true. Thus, $2^{i-1} (n-1) = 2^n - n - 1$. For $p(n+1) : k = n + 1$. Thus, $ 2^{i-1}(n+1-i) = 2^{i-1}(n-i) + 2^{i-1} = 2^n - n - 1+2^{i-1}.$ How do I proceed further with the $i$ index in the summation?

Comment: @kevin:  Do you want me to write down the whole solution? :) Then it wouldn't be a hint or pointer! :)

Comment: I got it now, I hadn't taken the summation into consideration

Comment: @kevin: happy to hear that! :)

Comment: Why is the induction on k and not on i? Is this the rule for summations that the summation variable is not the one upon which induction is done?

Comment: @kevin: you can consider it as a rule! An way, if you think a little, you find it meaningless to have induction on $i$. As the question is telling you, the claim is to prove the equality for $k \ge 1$ and hence $k$ is the thing! :)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to show is that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i-1}(k+1-i)=2^{k+1}-(k+1)-1$$
based on the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i-1}(k-i)=2^{k}-k-1$.

Start by expanding the LHS:-
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i-1}(k+1-i)&=\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}[2^{i-1}(k-i)+2^{i-1}]\\&=\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i-1}(k-i)}+2^{k}(-1)+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i-1}\\&=\color{blue}{2^k-k-1}-2^k+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i-1}\end{align}$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup, $ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k}2^{i} = 2^{k+1} -1$. Now, ${2^k-k-1}-2^k + 2^{k+1} -1 = 2^{k+1}-k-2 $ which is the required answer.